# Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Alea.dll "i32 is not struct type

Tags: c#, aleagpu

I am trying to use `Gpu.Default.For` from the Alea GPU library, but I keep getting an exception:

```
i32 is not a struct type error.
```

What does this error mean, and why am I getting it with this simple `Gpu.Default.For` loop?

```
for (Int32 j = 0; j <= TimePeriodArray.Length - 1; j++)
//Gpu.Default.For(0, TimePeriodArray.Length - 1, j =>
{
    Int32 days = TimePeriodArray[j];
    Double[] CalcResult = new Double[CloseArray.Length];

    for (Int32 Index = days; Index <= CloseArray.Length - 1; Index++)
    {
        Gpu.Default.For(Index - 1, Index - days, i =>
        {
            CalcResult[Index] = CalcResult[Index] + CloseArray[i];
        });

        CalcResult[Index] = CalcResult[Index] / days;
    }

    CalcResultsList.Add(CalcResult);
//});
}
```

Comment: Is [this](http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_3/doc/gpu_programming_csharp.html#parallel_for) the method you are asking about?

Comment: Yes, the error happens once the code tries to execute the Gpu.Default.For loop

Gpu.Default.For(Index - 1, Index - days, i =>
        {
            CalcResult[Index] = CalcResult[Index] + CloseArray[i];
        });

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask]. Along with enough code to duplicate the problem, this, in part, means providing the *exact* error text produced when running the code (as text in `code format`).

Comment: Could you humor me and set the inclusive value to 1 (the first param) of the For extension method, and the exclusive value to 10 (the second param) and tell me what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Two things: first, you new an array inside GPU code, which is not supported. Second, I guess `CalcResultsList` is of type `List`, which is also not supported. The reason is, it is not efficient to allocate new memory within GPU code. GPU code will be executed with many threads, allocation inside GPU code is not recommended.